# Azure SQL drops execution plan on tier change

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database, powershell-3.0, azure-automation

We have daily scale in and scale out in place for one database. We switch between Standard and Premium tier. During which stored procedures query execution plan gets dropped. From application the query timeout is sets to 30 Seconds. Some of these stored procedures take more time to complete execution.

Does anyone have a suggestion in place for this.

Right now I've kept an Azure automation powershell script to run some of these SPs so the execution plans get rebuild on a daily basis. Any other suggestions?

Comment: how are you guessing that these are due  to tier changes..?

Comment: With tier changes(higher to lower), you will get less memory and plans dropping is one posssibilty due to memory pressure

Comment: I have a script in place which would scale down db to basic tier. When sacaled back to Premium tier. I could see SQL trying to rebuild execution plan.

Comment: In standard tier parallel execution of queries won't work. Once ms support person told.

Comment: That may not be true totally

Comment: are you seeing any issues with this now(like plan drop)

Comment: Yes I observed that parallism is not working with Standard tier.

Comment: Could the parallism not working be the reason for dropping of execution plan ?

Comment: no ,its not the reason and parallelism works even in my basic tier ..plan drop reason is stated in my another comment as one possibilty

Comment: Memory pressure you mean ?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @thegameiswar
 
Thanks for the pointer. I will check internally to see if this is what is triggering the issue.

Comment: The procedure cache is cleared during any failover operation, including service level updates.